# AngularJS-rize bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I just started wondering...

Bootstrap is awesome, but the fact that everything has to be put in the "class" attribute just sucks. And I thought of something : why not replace

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
    <div class="panel-body"></div>
</div>
```

By registered div elements (I am thinking about angularJS directives)

```
<panel class="info">
    <phead></phead>
    <pbody></pbody>
</panel>
```

Would it just be boring/difficult to do (and maybe slow for the comp ?) or is there something else that I didn't think about and make it unuseful/impossible ?

Comment: Take a look at [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Also have a look at _web component_ and _shadow DOM_, which may occur in future standards.

Comment: Thanks for you refs, I googled web components and shadow DOM, but it's more like "let's hide all the div stuff", yet they are still using so many meaningless divs/spans. They are only using very few new HTML elements, and my question is more "why only so few ?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are talking about something not in the HTML standard currently.
First we can wait for new tags in future standards. But I don't think there might be a `<panel>` tag. If we defined `<panel>` in standard we can imagine that there must be other 3,000 tags together in standard like `<layer> <block> <board> <square> <surface>`... and that will make HTML a total mess.

Then maybe we can allow custom tags in HTML. But currently each tag has its own behavior, for `<div>` it has `display: block`, for `<span>` it has `display: inline` etc. We can't let every custom tag behave as `<div>` because there must be some tags we want them to be `inline`, or `flex`.

So we should have a way to define default behavior of custom tags. That's what web component does. You define the custom tag `<bs-panel>` and define its behavior via shadow dom. It has to be `<div>`s and `<span>`s finally, because saying "bs-panel looks like div" is ok but saying "bs-panel looks like bs-panel" is a joke.

So at last can we discard default behavior at all and put all of them in CSS? Yes we can. And we already has that. CSS can be used on XML documents, and you can write any tags you want and style them with CSS. But this method is not so widely used, maybe because styling everything from scratch is too boring.

Comment: "... and that will make HTML a total mess" --> I'm not sure I agree with that. When I look at my code, I see dozens and dozens of embedded `<div>`, and I don't even know which tag closes what element -- even syntax highlighting becomes useless if your closing tag is 100 lines below --.
I also wouldn't mind having `<layer> <block> <board> <square> <surface>`, even if I never use them at all. People would still have the choice of using these when they see fit, and/or classic `<div>`.

Comment: I mean the standard will be a total mess. People have to spend much longer time to learn HTML, or when they read `<layer>` in some other's code they have to seek the reference to determine what behavior the tag has. When there's thirty or fifty different unfamiliar tags in this document that will be a hard work. And if you only want semantic tags but not default behaviors, then XML+CSS is the best option. As long as we are still talking about HTML, default behaviors is a must to be considered.

Comment: Alright I had indeed in my mind something like XML + CSS. Thanks for your clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Or check out Attribute Modules for CSS, AMCSS... 
http://amcss.github.io/

Not using block level div elements, but HTML attributes and their values.  For example, instead of...

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large primary button</a>
```

You would do something like...

```
<a am-Button="primary large">Large primary button</a>
```

I'm still trying to figure out performance stats, but it's very very interesting none-the-less (from and OOCSS code perspective).

Comment: I would also be interested in performance stats (just by curiosity). And thanks for your link to AMCSS.